# Which is the best method to set up event tracking for new account signup steps in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js, analytics.js

Currently I'm using the following **analytics.js** method to track different funnels/goals and these get triggered on each specific page.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/ConversionEvents/Step1_MembershipPlan');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/ConversionEvents/Step2_AccountInformation');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/ConversionEvents/Step3_PaymentInformation');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/ConversionEvents/Step4_AccountConfirmation');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/ConversionEvents/Step5_ThankYou');
```

However, now that I switched to **gtag.js** I'm seeing what the best method would be to set these up.  I came up with the following 3 options.

**Option 1:**

```
gtag('event', 'sign_up', {'step_name': 'step1_membership_plan'});
```

**Option 2:**

```
gtag('event', 'pageview', {'step_name': 'step1_membership_plan'});
```

**Option 3:**

```
gtag('event', 'step1_membership_plan');
```

I'm leaning towards using **option 3** because it would be easier to view these events in GA4 since it will be listed as a different event name and it would be easier to create funnels.

From reading online, they say it's better to use the recommended/automatic events like **sign_up** and **pageview** for this but I'm not sure if then I can set up events to track the different parameters (e.g. **step_name**) that I set up for each step.

Which option would be the best to go with?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not clutter my GA4 with too many distinct event names.

But that's a matter of taste: If I understand Google's *limits* page correctly, web properties do not currently have a limit on distinctly named events, whereas app properties are limited to 500.
Ref.: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744?hl=en)

Instead, I would send the following events:

- `sign_up`, when a user has completed the registration, aka visits the thank you page.
- `sign_up_step_complete`, when a user has completed a step in the registration process. Sending the custom dimension `step_name` for each step.

(That is assuming that each step is just a virtual page view and does not actually send a `page_view` event to Google. If it *does* send a page_view, you can create the `sign_up_step_complete` event server-side based on the URL or not create an event at all and just use the `page_view`.)

This way, you're using the dafault `sign_up` event which might show up in a default GA report while also tracking intermediate steps in a separate custom event.

Finally, I would visualize the data in a free-form exploration funnel analysis.

Comment: Ok, great...ty for your help!  I'll try implementing this on my website.